# Reddit json api behaves differently when access it through a browser and nodejs request

Tags: node.js, reddit

I'm trying to access `secure_media` property of a post to download a v.redd.it media.

For example: when I try to access this [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/DiWHY/comments/c6wd68/how_could_this_possibly_be_practical/.json) from a browser, the secure_media property is not empty in the response, but when i GET it through nodejs request the secure_media is empty

Comment: Open Chrome devtools and then the network tab, load the link from above and check the request headers. Try adding these headers to your request in nodejs, one or multiple of these headers will probably make the difference in the response.

Comment: @seahorsepip   Tried almost all the headers, still same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are dealing with a crosspost submission, not the actual submission itself, which work a bit differently from normal submissions.

You can get the video information from the `secure_media` property of the first item in the `crosspost_parent_list` property. Here is part of the JSON structure for the post you linked:

```
[
  {
    "kind": "Listing",
    "data": {
      "modhash": "yg3o3tzdc136d53e2919218e00ef74e8fc38d97b9a22f34b60",
      "dist": 1,
      "children": [
        {
          "kind": "t3",
          "data": {
            "secure_media": null,
            "is_reddit_media_domain": true,
            "is_meta": false,
            "category": null,
            "num_comments": 9,
            "secure_media_embed": {},
            "crosspost_parent_list": [
              {
                "secure_media": {
                  "reddit_video": {
                    "fallback_url": "https://v.redd.it/kh2kirut06731/DASH_1080?source=fallback",
                    "height": 1080,
                    "width": 608,
                    "scrubber_media_url": "https://v.redd.it/kh2kirut06731/DASH_96",
                    "dash_url": "https://v.redd.it/kh2kirut06731/DASHPlaylist.mpd",
                    "duration": 53,
                    "hls_url": "https://v.redd.it/kh2kirut06731/HLSPlaylist.m3u8",
                    "is_gif": true,
                    "transcoding_status": "completed"
                  }
                },
                "is_reddit_media_domain": true,
                "discussion_type": null,
                "mod_reports": [],
                "is_video": true
              }
            ],
            "created": 1561824841,
            "link_flair_type": "text",
            "wls": 6,
            "banned_by": null,
```